# Android unable to play html5 video when served from Wordpress

Tags: android, wordpress, html5-video

So I've spent the last 24 hours trying to get html5 video working across the board. I initially could get MP4s found around the web to play on Android, but when I swapped my own MP4, all I get is a black screen

I went down the path of trying every possible encoding method I could find. I finally found that if I simply host the video file on a different server, everything worked.

I hooked up my Nexus-5 to Chromes dev console, and notice the request for the mp4 is being canceled:

[image: Request being canceled]

Everything works fine on chrome on the computer, but chrome on Android is showing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Turns out the server was using Apache basic authentication. For some reason, android was not sending the appropriate cookies when retrieving the mp4 (despite being logged in).

Results were, that everything would display except the mp4 that was being pulled without cookies, thus authentication failed.